# How do I solve a maximization equation with constraints in R?

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I'm having difficulties solving a maximization problem with constraints in R.

[image: Formular]

I've tried using `constrOptim()`, but i can't figure out what theta is or should be equal to.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you show the code you have so far so we can help you get it working?

Comment: Also, does the notation `x^{*u}` mean `x^u` or something else?

Comment: Further, `q` only appears in the RHS of the second set of constraints, meaning it could just be set to a huge value and that class of constraints would always hold. Are you sure there isn't a typo in your formulation (e.g. `q` also appearing in the objective)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the logarithm to get linear constraints and then use the constrOptim function.